# Newbie: Raspberry Pi Games Emulator 12v Power supply - Car

Tags: emulation, voltage, cars

I have Corsa D 2007 (wife's old car). I've recently stuck one of the cheap eBay Android Touch screens into it for the laugh (came with reversing camera!) - *side note for £30 I'm pleasantly surprised with it!*

It also has a Video Input on it so I was thinking for a bit of a giggle just purely for my own amusement I was thinking how a Raspberry Pi in the glovebox with an emulator and a few games on it would be just stupid enough to entertain me for a few days doing the setup.

I know literally 0 to do with the raspberry pi boxes so my first real question is this.  Will the above setup work (12v input)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it will work, but Raspberry Pi works with 5V, then you'll have to provide it with a 2A USB phone charger.

As for me, I would insert a battery bank between charger and Raspberry to avoid the leak of current.

Particularly for the Raspberry Pi 4, your need 3A, which doesn't exist in chargers phones, then you'll have to transform 12v in 5V another way.

Comment: *"provide it with a 2A USB phone charger"* -> Phone chargers are not the best choice for providing power to live electronics that do not have an internal battery of their own because chargers are not intended for that purpose, and the purpose of recharging batteries does not require that the charger be able to respond to sudden fluctuations in current draw (it might even be that they are designed *not* to).  Put another way, "phone charger" != "general purpose power supply", although they have become so ubiquitous it is easy to see them that way.